# strange bug when loading entities in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, clr, entities, bag

I am getting an error in NHibernate.Collection.PersistentBag class when trying to load entities:

*The value "MyProject.DomainModel.Operator" is not of type "MyProject.DomainModel.Operator" and cannot be used in this generic collection.*

Notice that both value types are exactly the same. I've double-checked them in a comparer tool.

NHibernate is failing to add the value to a List collection at line bag.Add(element) .

The **element** variable is actually of type *object{DecoratorAopProxy_9cf850624c7e4ef9a8e2d9694bed26fd}*. I've noticed that the objects that can be successfully added to this list are of type *object{MyProject.DomainModel.Operator}*. This type is obtained from "quick watch" feature in VS2012 from the "Type" column.

Does anyone have an idea as to why NHibernate changes the type of this particular object to a proxy while others have pure entity types?

```
<class name ="PersonRole" table ="tblPersonRole" mutable ="false">
    <id name="Id" column="PersonRoleID" type="Int32" access ="nosetter.lowercase-underscore">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <discriminator  formula="case when RoleID in (2,4,5,6) THEN RoleID ELSE 0 END" />
   <subclass discriminator-value="4" name="AccountManagerRole">      
      <bag name="Operators" >
        <key column="OperatorID"></key>
        <one-to-many class="BaseOperator"/>
        <loader query-ref="LoadAllocatedOperators_ACCOUNTMANAGER"/>
      </bag>
    </subclass>
</class>

<class name="BaseOperator" table="tblOperator" lazy="true" >      
    <id name="Id" column="OperatorID" access ="nosetter.lowercase-underscore" type="Int32" unsaved-value="null">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <discriminator column="OperatorType" type="string"  />
    <subclass discriminator-value ="OPR" name ="Operator" lazy="true">
      <bag name="Customers" access="nosetter.camelcase-underscore" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true" fetch="join"  >
        <key column="OperatorId" />
            <one-to-many class="MyProject.DomainModel.Customer, MyProject" not-found="ignore" />
        </bag>
        <subclass discriminator-value ="OPR2" name ="Operator2"  lazy="true" />
    </subclass>
</class>
```

So I do something like "*select distinct accManager from AccountManagerRole accManager*", which results in operators being loaded one at a time using their ID, and NHibernate crashes on one of them.

Comment: Is the `Operator` class lazy loaded?

Comment: Could you post relevant parts of your mappings ?

Comment: @PaulPhillips, yes, it seems so.

Comment: @jbl, I've just did it, please take a look.

Comment: the problem seems to be a proxy inheriting OperatorBase instead of Operator. Maybe the discriminator value returned is false. I would check the generated sql and the results